# Compare 2 arrays with array_diff

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays that I need to compare:

The first array contains `zipcodes` as `keys` and `dates` as `values`:

```
Array ( [1000] => Array ( [0] => 2014-12-01 am [1] => 2014-12-01 pm [2] => 2014-12-05 am [3] => 2014-12-05 pm [4] => 2014-12-08 am [5] => 2014-12-08 pm [6] => 2014-12-12 am [7] => 2014-12-12 pm [8] => 2014-12-15 am [9] => 2014-12-15 pm [10] => 2014-12-19 am [11] => 2014-12-19 pm [12] => 2014-12-22 am [13] => 2014-12-22 pm ) [1020] => Array ( [0] => 2014-12-01 am [1] => 2014-12-01 pm [2] => 2014-12-02 am [3] => 2014-12-02 pm [4] => 2014-12-05 am [5] => 2014-12-05 pm [6] => 2014-12-08 am [7] => 2014-12-08 pm [8] => 2014-12-09 am [9] => 2014-12-09 pm [10] => 2014-12-12 am [11] => 2014-12-12 pm [12] => 2014-12-15 am [13] => 2014-12-15 pm [14] => 2014-12-16 am [15] => 2014-12-16 pm [16] => 2014-12-19 am [17] => 2014-12-22 am [18] => 2014-12-22 pm [19] => 2014-12-23 am [20] => 2014-12-23 pm ) (...) )
```

And then the second array has the dates that stored at least 4 times in the database, like this example:

```
Array ( [0] => 2014-12-01 pm [1] => 2014-12-12 am )
```

I am trying to use the array_diff to create a new array without this dates, but it isn't working.

What a I missing? Any ideas how to make this work?

Thanks in advance

Edit:

Here's the full code

```
global $woocommerce;

$dates = array(
    '1000' => array('2014-12-01 am', '2014-12-01 pm', '2014-12-05 am', '2014-12-05 pm', '2014-12-08 am', '2014-12-08 pm', '2014-12-12 am', '2014-12-12 pm', '2014-12-15 am', '2014-12-15 pm', '2014-12-19 am', '2014-12-19 pm', '2014-12-22 am','2014-12-22 pm'),
    '1020' => array('2014-12-01 am', '2014-12-01 pm', '2014-12-02 am', '2014-12-02 pm', '2014-12-05 am', '2014-12-05 pm', '2014-12-08 am', '2014-12-08 pm', '2014-12-09 am', '2014-12-09 pm', '2014-12-12 am', '2014-12-12 pm', '2014-12-15 am', '2014-12-15 pm', '2014-12-16 am', '2014-12-16 pm', '2014-12-19 am', '2014-12-22 am', '2014-12-22 pm', '2014-12-23 am', '2014-12-23 pm'),
    '1030' => array('2014-12-05 am', '2014-12-05 pm', '2014-12-12 am', '2014-12-12 pm', '2014-12-19 am', '2014-12-19 pm'),
    '1030' => array('2014-12-05 am', '2014-12-05 pm', '2014-12-12 am', '2014-12-12 pm', '2014-12-19 am', '2014-12-19 pm'),
    '1040' => array('2014-12-04 am', '2014-12-04 pm', '2014-12-11 am', '2014-12-11 pm', '2014-12-18 am', '2014-12-18 pm'),
    '1050' => array('2014-12-03 am', '2014-12-03 pm', '2014-12-10 am', '2014-12-10 pm', '2014-12-17 am', '2014-12-17 pm'),
    '1060' => array('2014-12-03 am', '2014-12-03 pm', '2014-12-10 am', '2014-12-10 pm', '2014-12-17 am', '2014-12-17 pm'),
    '1070' => array('2014-12-02 am', '2014-12-02 pm', '2014-12-09 am', '2014-12-09 pm', '2014-12-16 am', '2014-12-16 pm', '2014-12-23 am', '2014-12-23 pm'),
    '1080' => array('2014-12-02 am', '2014-12-02 pm', '2014-12-09 am', '2014-12-09 pm', '2014-12-16 am', '2014-12-16 pm', '2014-12-23 am', '2014-12-23 pm'),
    '1081' => array('2014-12-02 am', '2014-12-02 pm', '2014-12-09 am', '2014-12-09 pm', '2014-12-16 am', '2014-12-16 pm', '2014-12-23 am', '2014-12-23 pm'),
    '1082' => array('2014-12-02 am', '2014-12-02 pm', '2014-12-09 am', '2014-12-09 pm', '2014-12-16 am', '2014-12-16 pm', '2014-12-23 am', '2014-12-23 pm'),
    '1083' => array('2014-12-02 am', '2014-12-02 pm', '2014-12-09 am', '2014-12-09 pm', '2014-12-16 am', '2014-12-16 pm', '2014-12-23 am', '2014-12-23 pm'),
    '1090' => array('2014-12-02 am', '2014-12-02 pm', '2014-12-09 am', '2014-12-09 pm', '2014-12-16 am', '2014-12-16 pm', '2014-12-23 am', '2014-12-23 pm'),
    '1120' => array('2014-12-01 am', '2014-12-01 pm', '2014-12-05 am', '2014-12-05 pm', '2014-12-08 am', '2014-12-08 pm', '2014-12-12 am', '2014-12-12 pm', '2014-12-15 am', '2014-12-15 pm', '2014-12-19 am', '2014-12-19 pm', '2014-12-22 am', '2014-12-22 pm'),
    '1130' => array('2014-12-01 am', '2014-12-01 pm', '2014-12-08 am', '2014-12-08 pm', '2014-12-15 am', '2014-12-15 pm', '2014-12-22 am', '2014-12-22 pm'),
    '1140' => array('2014-12-05 am', '2014-12-05 pm', '2014-12-12 am', '2014-12-12 pm', '2014-12-19', 'am'),
    '1150' => array('2014-12-04 am', '2014-12-04 pm', '2014-12-11 am', '2014-12-11 pm', '2014-12-18 am', '2014-12-18 pm'),
    '1160' => array('2014-12-04 am', '2014-12-04 pm', '2014-12-11 am', '2014-12-11 pm', '2014-12-18 am', '2014-12-18 pm'),
    '1170' => array('2014-12-03 am', '2014-12-03 pm', '2014-12-10 am', '2014-12-10 pm', '2014-12-17 am', '2014-12-17 pm'),
    '1180' => array('2014-12-03 am', '2014-12-03 pm', '2014-12-10 am', '2014-12-10 pm', '2014-12-17 am', '2014-12-17 pm'),
    '1190' => array('2014-12-03 am', '2014-12-03 pm', '2014-12-10 am', '2014-12-10 pm', '2014-12-17 am', '2014-12-17 pm'),
    '1200' => array('2014-12-04 am', '2014-12-04 pm', '2014-12-11 am', '2014-12-11 pm', '2014-12-18 am', '2014-12-18 pm'),
    '1210' => array('2014-12-05 am', '2014-12-05 pm', '2014-12-12 am', '2014-12-12 pm', '2014-12-19 am', '2014-12-19 pm'),
    '1620' => array('2014-12-03 am', '2014-12-03 pm', '2014-12-10 am', '2014-12-10 pm', '2014-12-17 am', '2014-12-17 pm'),
    '1630' => array('2014-12-03 am', '2014-12-03 pm', '2014-12-10 am', '2014-12-10 pm', '2014-12-17 am', '2014-12-17 pm'),
    '1650' => array('2014-12-03 am', '2014-12-03 pm', '2014-12-10 am', '2014-12-10 pm', '2014-12-17 am', '2014-12-17 pm'),
    '1702' => array('2014-12-02 am', '2014-12-02 pm', '2014-12-09 am', '2014-12-09 pm', '2014-12-16 am', '2014-12-16 pm', '2014-12-23 am', '2014-12-23 pm'),
    '1780' => array('2014-12-02 am', '2014-12-02 pm', '2014-12-09 am', '2014-12-09 pm', '2014-12-16 am', '2014-12-16 pm', '2014-12-23 am', '2014-12-23 pm'),
    '1800' => array('2014-12-01 am', '2014-12-01 pm', '2014-12-08 am', '2014-12-08 pm', '2014-12-15 am', '2014-12-15 pm', '2014-12-22 am', '2014-12-22 pm'),
    '1850' => array('2014-12-01 am', '2014-12-01 pm', '2014-12-08 am', '2014-12-08 pm', '2014-12-15 am', '2014-12-15 pm', '2014-12-22 am', '2014-12-22 pm'),
    '1853' => array('2014-12-01 am', '2014-12-01 pm', '2014-12-08 am', '2014-12-08 pm', '2014-12-15 am', '2014-12-15 pm', '2014-12-22 am', '2014-12-22 pm'),
    '1930' => array('2014-12-04 am', '2014-12-04 pm', '2014-12-11 am', '2014-12-11 pm', '2014-12-18 am', '2014-12-18 pm'),
    '1932' => array('2014-12-04 am', '2014-12-04 pm', '2014-12-11 am', '2014-12-11 pm', '2014-12-18 am', '2014-12-18 pm'),
    '1950' => array('2014-12-04 am', '2014-12-04 pm', '2014-12-11 am', '2014-12-11 pm', '2014-12-18 am', '2014-12-18 pm'),
    '1970' => array('2014-12-04 am', '2014-12-04 pm', '2014-12-11 am', '2014-12-11 pm', '2014-12-18 am', '2014-12-18 pm')
);  

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'shop_order',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'shop_order_status',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array('pending', 'processing', 'completed', 'on-hold')
        )
    )
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);

$delivery_dates = array();

while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    $order_id = $loop->post->ID;

    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);

    if(array_key_exists($order->billing_delivery_date, $delivery_dates))
        $delivery_dates[$order->billing_delivery_date]++;
    else
        $delivery_dates[$order->billing_delivery_date] = 1;

endwhile;

$max_deliveries = 4;
$result = array_filter(
    $delivery_dates, function ($value) use($max_deliveries) {
        return ($value >= $max_deliveries);
    }
);

$reverse = array_flip($result);

$delivery_dates_db = array_values($reverse);

$new_dates = array_diff($dates, $delivery_dates_db);

print_r($new_dates);
```

Comment: you better post the exact code which doesn't work

Comment: @MinusFour yes, the 1000 is a zipcode. I added my full php code

Comment: I think you'll have to iterate $dates array with a foreach() and do individual array_diff. Otherwise, I think you'll just end up with a mix of both arrays. By the way, what's the purpose of the foreach of $reverse? Isn't it just doing nothing to it?

Comment: When I retrieve the dates from the db I get a array like this `Array ( [2014-12-03 pm] => 2 [2014-12-03 am] => 3 )` so I am using the array_flip and the foreach to get an array with the dates as values and not keys. Edit: just commented the foreach to test and you are right, it is doing nothing

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: What is the desired structure you want to achieve?

Comment: @robbmj What I want to achieve is to create a new array without the dates I retrieve from the database, ie, the first array without those dates

Comment: Actually, the first array you mention, it's different from the code. You have another array inside they key. Basically, `'key' => array(array('dates'))`

Comment: how about `array_keys($the_first_array);`?

Comment: @robbmj that's not what I want, I want the keys and the dates, but not the dates retrieved from the db

Comment: Does this do what you want it to do?
    `foreach ($dates as &$d_arr) {
     $d_arr[0] = array_diff($d_arr[0], $delivery_dates_db);
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, at the moment you have an unnecessary array nested.

Take a look at the first entry:

```
<?php
$dates = array(
'1000' => array(
    array('2014-12-01 am', '2014-12-01 pm', '2014-12-05 am', '2014-12-05 pm', '2014-12-08 am', '2014-12-08 pm', '2014-12-12 am', '2014-12-12 pm', '2014-12-15 am', '2014-12-15 pm', '2014-12-19 am', '2014-12-19 pm', '2014-12-22 am','2014-12-22 pm')
)
....
```

You could have it like this:

```
<?php
$dates = array(
'1000' => array('2014-12-01 am', '2014-12-01 pm', '2014-12-05 am', '2014-12-05 pm', '2014-12-08 am', '2014-12-08 pm', '2014-12-12 am', '2014-12-12 pm', '2014-12-15 am', '2014-12-15 pm', '2014-12-19 am', '2014-12-19 pm', '2014-12-22 am','2014-12-22 pm'),
....
```

If you intend on doing array_diff then you'll have to iterate $dates to compare each value within it. (This codes only works without the nested array).

```
<?php
foreach($dates as $key => value){
  $dates[$key] = array_diff($value, $delivery_dates_db);
}
```

This code should work with the nested array.

```
<?php
foreach($dates as $key => value){
  $dates[$key] = array_diff($value[0], $delivery_dates_db);
}
```

I'm not sure why you have nested another array.

Comment: Thanks man, I just removed the nested arrays and used your first solution, the array seems to be created correctly and without the dates retrieved from the db!